# SharePoint JSOM get taxonomy recursive

Tags: javascript, recursion, sharepoint-2013

I have a problem concerning getting a tree of terms recursively from a term group using JSOM / javascript.

The problem is that I do get all values recursive but that the order is totally wrong.

```
 function recurseTerms(currentTerm, loops){
loops++;
var terms = currentTerm.get_terms(); 
context.load(terms); 
context.executeQueryAsync( 
    function () {
        var termsEnum = terms.getEnumerator();

        while (termsEnum.moveNext()) {
            var newCurrentTerm = termsEnum.get_current();
            termstext += newCurrentTerm.get_name() + "<br>";

            //Check if term has child terms.
            if (newCurrentTerm.get_termsCount() > 0) {
                recurseTerms(newCurrentTerm, loops);
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("resultsDiv").innerHTML = termstext;
 },
 function () {

//failure to load terms

});
```

So I call the function recurseTerms with as first parameter the Term-object (root) and 0 as loops (only for formatting purposes). My terms as viewed in the management tool is:

```
Level 1
--Level 1a
--Level 1b
Level 2
Level 3
--Level 3a
----Level 3a
------Level 3a1
------Level 3a2
--------Level 3a2a
--------Level 3a2b
----Level 3b
```

But unfortunately, the output of my function (termstext) is :

```
Level 1
Level 2
Level 3
Level 1a
Level 1b
Level 3a
Level 3b
Level 3a1
Level 3a2
Level 3a2a
Level 3a2b
```

So I would assume that when the function reaches the Term 'level 1', he would detect the children and recurse, by printing the children terms beneath 'Level 1' but apparantely this is not the case.

I know what the problem is but I'm at loss for a solution :(
Can anyone point me the good way pls?
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i fixed this a long time ago using javascript promises. When level 1 is retrieved, we can then recall the function etc...

Comment: Please share the solution that may help people like me looking for a solution

Comment: OK, its been a while but i'll try to lookup this code again ;-)